# handling/force timeout stale connections in connection pool in case of DB connectivity issues

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am facing RDS connectivity issues sometimes. So when this happen, all the connections in my connection pool become stale. With stale connections in the pool i am facing some high latency issues.

1. With `testConnectionOnCheckout = true`, How can set a timeout for getting a connection from c3p0's connection pool? Because when my application tries to obtain the connection from the pool, all the connections in the pool are first checked if they are stale and after that when pool is exhausted, then i get an exception after `checkoutTimeout` interval. SO if my checkout interval is 1000 ms and it takes around 100 ms to check stale connection and i have 30 connections in pool, my request would be stuck for 100*30+1000=4000 ms. Is there a way I can put a timeout to obtain a connection (doesn't matter if pool is exhausted or not).
2. With periodic connection checking, I face a weird issue in latency. I have set JDBC read timeout to 2000 ms. When I make calls to my API, some calls do throw an exception within 2000 ms but a few calls take around 15 sec or more which keeps my thread busy and make my service unavailable for those APIs which don't depend on database. The behavior about this high latency is every 6th call to the API takes longer time. I am not sure how could that happen.

Comment: So what do you mean by "periodic connection checking"? do you have an idleConnnectionTestPeriod set? are you using a goof preferredTestQuery? these are things that might help get a prompt refresh of stale Connections.